# How to make Javascript Scroll less Jumpy

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my defense - I don't know Javascript amazingly.

Here's my webpage: www.andrewjalexander.com

Here's the code someone helped me to get:

```
window.onscroll = moveEle;
function moveEle() {
//Alter top to be how many pixels you want from the top of the window
var top = 100;
ele = document.getElementById('sidebar');
if(document.body && document.body.scrollTop) {
ele.style.top = (document.body.scrollTop + top) + "px";
} else if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
ele.style.top = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + top) + "px";
}
}
```

The scrolling seems incredibly jumpy. I tried CSS but the sidebar kept overlapping with the main div.

Is there a way to get scrolling, and no overlap with any of the divs?

Comment: what you mean overlaping? resizing the window the menu gets overlaped on the main content?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, with CSS alone. With this Javascript, no overlap, but jumpiness.

Comment: it can overlap when the screen size is smaller bu in that case make the ul size in % like .ul {width: 5%}  5% will be 5 in a big or small screen.

Comment: Er, I don't quite understand what you mean - can you be more specific?

Comment: If you shrink the window and scroll over, it does still.

Comment: Are you looking for a smooth scroll, where the page automates the scrolling (basically have the browser mimic the user scrolling with the mousewheel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/myprg/3/

just added positon: fixed to

it's now `<ul style ="position: fixed;">`

it overlaps but it has to be a really small screen. still looks smooth.

Comment: Um, now the UL text always overlaps main.

Comment: I took off the bottom scroll whe the page is resized. I tested it a my laptop monitor, and I have a big  screen attached also, so the page looks good on both screens. http://jsfiddle.net/myprg/3/

Comment: here is an example of floating menu with jquery, but I can tell you it is not so smoth also. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/

or just the demo https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/018_Floating_Menu/demo/dhtml_float_menu_final_nettut.html